# How to install imagemagick extension for PHP5 on Xubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Tags: 64-bit, xubuntu, php, imagemagick

How to properly install imagemagick extension for PHP5 on Xubuntu 12.04.1 LTS?

**convert --version**

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-08-17 Q16
```

**sudo pecl install imagick**

```
...
checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... configure: error: no. You need at least Imagemagick version 6.2.4 to use Imagick.
```

What am i doing wrong? )

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.0.1.tgz
tar zxvf imagick-3.0.1.tgz
cd imagick*
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Thanks @unni, but when i do: "./configure", there is the same error message in the end of the output: "checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... configure: error: no. You need at least Imagemagick version 6.2.4 to use Imagick."